# Can client side validation in Python OpenAPI generator be set via the CLI?

Tags: python, command-line, openapi-generator

I can see this has been implemented as an option in https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/4137

I have set `local_configuration_vars.client_side_validation = False` and this works as desired and fixes my issue

However, I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same effect when generating the library via the CLI (this will mean the removal of the above manual step)

Things I have tried with no joy:

- `generate -i schema.json -g python -o python_client --client_side_validation=false`
- `generate -i schema.json -g python -o python_client --clientSideValidation=false`
- `generate -i schema.json -g python -o python_client --additional-properties=client_side_validation=false`